# VBA coding - copying a range of cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies if this is a simple thing to do, but I'm re-learning VBA after years of non-use. I have a worksheet where I need to find a specific cell within that workbook based on the text within that cell. I then need to copy the whole row that contains this cell, and the three rows below, making a range of four entire rows. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What have you googled? This should be easily found with a quick google search.

Answer (score 0):

You have not indicated where you wish to paste the material, but:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim s As String, sh As Worksheet, r As Range

    s = "happiness"
    For Each sh In Sheets
        Set r = Cells.Find(What:=s)
        If Not r Is Nothing Then
            r.Resize(4, 1).EntireRow.Copy
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Here we are searching for happiness.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I've used the code that you suggest and it does find and highlight the text necessary. In answer to the other reply, let me explain further:   I'm preparing a form where I need a macro that will replicate four rows of the blank form - these are the four rows that this code has highlighted. The first part of my code will need to highlight the rows, copy them, and insert them as a second four row block. This may need to be done several times, to add 4, 8 or 12 lines. The second piece of code will need to find any extra sets of four rows, and delete the entire lines.

Comment: OK, an update... I have managed the first part! Now the next part is to identify how many of these blocks of lines I have (I'm guessing it's a "countif" function), and then deleting all blocks of four lines except one. I'm getting the hang of it, but very slowly...